# Change persistence type of Windows Credentials from "Enterprise" to "Local computer" via cmdkey?

Tags: windows, credentials

I'm trying to add credentials for remote desktop connection via the [cmdkey command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmdkey)

```
cmdkey /add:TERMSRV/myserver /user:MyUser /pass:MyPassword
```

I wanted to check that this added correctly via the Credentials Manager GUI `control.exe /name Microsoft.CredentialManager` then `Windows Credentials` but the entry is saved with the persistence type of "Enterprise" which I don't think the Remote Desktop Client on Windows 10 likes. I have the belief that by modifying this to be "Local Computer" will solve the issue.

[image]

How can I modify the persistence type from "Enterprise" to "Local Computer"? A scriptable solution is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can modify the persistence type for existing credential.

But you can create a new credential through powershell with proper persistence. you need to install the below powershell module.
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CredentialManager/2.0
and then run the below cmdlet.

```
New-StoredCredential -Target Test -UserName test -Password test -Comment "test" -Persist Enterprise
```